# React, state update function from map with target name and value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update the state, the current func (handleLabelChange) theoretically works (updating state), but I want to add name instead of **textOne** and value **"????"** dynamically from the textarea field or any other field. Some kind of target.name and target.value, but I don't know how to deal with it.

```
handleLabelChange = id => {
const updatedItems = this.state.items.map(item => {
  if (item.id === id) {
    return {
      ...item,
      textOne: "????"  // grab textarea name and value here 
    };
  } else {
    return item;
  }
});

this.setState({
  items: updatedItems
});
```

};

JSX inside map function:

```
{this.state.items.map(el => (

<textarea rows="5" placeholder="Text here..." name="textOne" onChange={() => this.handleLabelChange(el.id)}></textarea>

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this on the textarea:

```
onChange={this.handleLabelChange(el.id, 'name')}
```

Where the second argument is the property, and then handleLabelChange looks like this

```
function handleLabelChange(id, property) {
  return ev => {
    const newVal = ev.target.value;

    const updatedItems = this.state.items.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        const newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
        newItem[property] = newVal;
        return newItem;
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      items: updatedItems
    });
  }
}
```

Your handleLabelChange returns the callback function, rather than *being* the callback function

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to solve it, if someone have a similar problem, it is my solution.

As TKoL suggested function needed args: id, name, value, ({target: {id, value, name}}), then in my case, I needed to change the id from string to number.

```
handleLabelChange = ({target: {id, value, name}}) => {
const idToNumber = Number(id);
const updatedItems = this.state.items.map(item => {
  if (item.id === idToNumber) {
    return {
      ...item,
      [name]: value
    };
  } else {
    return item;
  }
});

this.setState({
  items: updatedItems
});
}
```

JSX

```
{this.state.items.map(el => (

<textarea rows="5" placeholder="Text here..." id={el.id} name="textOne" onChange={this.handleLabelChange}></textarea>

}
```